# Подобно тому(,) как

Tags: запятые

Следует ли обособлять это словосочетание запятыми? Если да, то запятую следует ставить перед словосочетанием или в его середине?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обособлять можно как весь оборот, так и ставить запятую перед "как" и закрывать в конце части, относящейся к этому "как", если есть продолжение. Во втором случае перед началом оборота запятая не нужна. Выбор определяется интонацией автора (если запятая перед "как", делается смысловое ударение на "тому").

Вот об этом на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_539).